# Overloading cout as a Non Friend Helper Operator

Tags: c++

I've got these instructions for an assignment that have put me through a loop here. I need to overload the insertion operator to print out an objects datamembers. However, it states that the overloader has to be a non-friend helper operator.

If that's the case, how can it ever access the private datamembers if its not a 'friend'? And if this is possible, why should I avoid using 'friend'?

Here is what it says word for word:

- a helper non-friend operator that inserts the stored string into the left ostream operand.
  This operator prefaces the string with the number of the insertion and increment that number

I'm somewhat new to C++ so I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's not a friend, it needs to use the object's public interface (ergo, you need to write the object's public interface to include the access required by the insertion operator).

For example, you might do something like this:

```
class thing { 
    std::string name; 
public:
    std::string get_name() const { return name; }
    // ...
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, thing const &t) { 
    return os << t.get_name();
}
```

Note that I'm definitely *not* recommending this as good practice--rather the contrary, I think it's *often* a better idea for the insertion operator to be a friend. But if you're in a class and you're prohibited from doing things the right way, you do what you have to...

Comment: I would guess something has to be different. How exactly would I go about doing that?

Comment: @SomeDeveloper: I've added an example.

Comment: Thanks a ton Jerry. Yeah, it seems odd. But alas, I think its just to get people 'thinking' rather than enforce proper practices. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JerryCoffin I disagree. Insertion Operators should not be `friend`s as they output the logical value of an object into the stream. The logical value is what you can see from outside, not a dump of internal values no one apart from the class implementer should see. Ergo...

Comment: @Loopunroller: You're welcome to disagree if you want, but you're clearly wrong. The object should be an object, not a bunch of pieces. The outside world should treat it as an object, but the insertion operation often needs access to the internal pieces that most of the world shouldn't see.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Let me get this straight: The outside world shouldn't know of private/protected members, but they can output the values of them through a function? Moreover i reckon there are less `operator<<`'s that are `friend`s than those that aren't.

Comment: @Loopunroller: The rest of the program doesn't get (at least direct) access to those fields, no. Yes, there are a lot of people who write crappy code.