# Why is friend keyword required when overloading operator<<?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In the following example all my members are public so I don't understand why I still need to add the `friend` keyword. Moreover, this method belongs to a `Point` instance, so I also don't understand why I should refer to my attributes through `const Point% p`. In the `+` overload only the foreign instance is received.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Point {
    int x, y;
    Point(int x, int y): x(x), y(y) {};
    Point operator+(const Point& other) const {
        return Point(x + other.x, x + other.y);
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point& p) {
        return os << "(" << p.x << "," << p.y << ")";
    }
};

int main() {
    Point p = Point(4,7) + Point(8,3);
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
}
```

Similar questions such as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813364/overloading-cout-as-a-non-friend-helper-operator) are not really helpful in this case.

Comment: The Big Clue is that it’s *not* a member function at all.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You marked this as a duplicate, but I do not understand the answer given: `ergo, you need to write the object's public interface to include the access required by the insertion operator`. All my attributes are public...

Comment: @molbdnilo Why is this the case for the `+` overloading then?

Comment: I cannot remember that I had to make any stream output `operator<<` a `friend` of the output class. Stream output operators output usually which can be retrieved from the `public` part of a class. Hence, no `friend`ship needed. Of course, you have to define it as free function. The `friend` syntax seems for me like a "back door" to put a free function definition inside a `class` declaration. Such convoluted things, I try to prevent in my code as best as possible... ;-)

Comment: You're right, the "duplicate" doesn't address this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't have to make the stream inserter here a friend. The problem is that the code defines the inserter **inside the class definition**. Without any decorations it would be an ordinary member function, and calling it would be a syntactic nightmare. You could make it a `static` member, but that's counterintuitive. The reason that `friend` makes it works is a side effect: marking it as a `friend` pushes its definition outside the class definition. So instead of using `friend`, just define it outside the class definition.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Point {
    int x, y;
    Point(int x, int y): x(x), y(y) {};
    Point operator+(const Point& other) const {
        return Point(x + other.x, x + other.y);
    }

};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point& p) {
    return os << "(" << p.x << "," << p.y << ")";
}

int main() {
    Point p = Point(4,7) + Point(8,3);
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The reason it would be wrong to make it a member function is because you would change the operator's signature to include the implicit `this`. If you tried to use the operator normally, you would probably get an error stating you provided too many arguments.

Comment: @PhilipNelson -- you could call it with `p.operator<<(std::cout, p);`. As I said, a syntactic nightmare!

Comment: Fair enough. However, it is interesting and educational to know that you can call operators this way, even though you'd probably never do it. For learners, operators are just function calls coated in syntactic sugar.